# Discrete Exponential Martingale - Properties

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

This question is about the discrete exponential martingale.
Let $(Y_n)_n$ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables
with $m_{Y}(t) :=\mathbb{E}\left[e^{t Y_{1}}\right]<\infty, t \in \mathbb{R}$. I want to show that
\begin{align*}
M_{n} :=\frac{1}{m_{Y}(t)} \exp \left(t \sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_{i}\right)
\end{align*}
is a martingale.
But I didn't know how to proof that \begin{align*}
\begin{aligned} \mathbb{E}\left[M_{n+1} | \mathcal{F}_{n}\right] &=\frac{1}{m_{Y}(t)} \mathbb{E}\left[\exp \left(t \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} Y_{i}\right) | \mathcal{F}_{n}\right] \\ &=\frac{1}{m_{Y}(t)}\left\{\mathbb{E}\left[\exp \left(t Y_{n+1}\right) | \mathcal{F}_{n}\right]+\sum_{i=1}^{n} \mathbb{E}\left[\exp \left(t Y_{i}\right) | \mathcal{F}_{n}\right]\right\} = ... = M_n\end{aligned} 
\end{align*}

Comment: First of all, $e^{t\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} Y_i}$ is not equal to $e^{t Y_{n+1}}+\sum_{i=1}^n e^{t Y_i}$ so already you need to be more careful. Exponentials of sums turn into products of exponentials....

Comment: Yes, I know. But I thought that, since the $Y_i$ are independent, I can write the expectation value of a product of independent events as the sum of the expectation values. So $\mathbb{E}[\prod_i \exp(t Y_i) ] = \sum_i \mathbb{E}[\exp(t Y_i)]$.

Comment: Uhh.. I can't say I've ever seen a result that says $\mathbb{E}(X_1 \cdot \dotsc \cdot X_n)=\sum_i \mathbb{E}(X_i)$ when the $X_i$ are independent... care to quote that source? Are you sure you aren't thinking of the true property that independence means to multiply i.e. $\mathbb{E}(X_1 \cdot \dotsc \cdot X_n)=\mathbb{E}(X_1)\cdot \dotsc \cdot \mathbb{E}(X_n)$? Surely you are mistaking some properties of logs/exponentials and expectation of products under independence... anyway I am writing up an answer to carry through the work.

Comment: Oh, you're totally right. I mixed it up with $\mathrm{E}\left[\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} X_{i}\right]=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \mathrm{E}\left[X_{i}\right]$.

Comment: Use the "pulling out what is known" property
$$\mathbb{E}(M_{n+1} | \mathscr{F}_n)=\frac{e^{t \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i}}{m_Y(t)}\mathbb{E}(e^{tY_{n+1}} | \mathscr{F}_n),$$
finally $Y_{n+1}$ is independent of $\mathscr{F}_n$ and since $h(\cdot)=e^{t \cdot}$ is Borel, so is $h(Y_{n+1})$. Thus,
$$\mathbb{E}(M_{n+1} | \mathscr{F}_n)=\frac{e^{t \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i}}{m_Y(t)}\mathbb{E}(e^{tY_{n+1}})=e^{t \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i}=M_n m_Y(t)$$
so either I have messed up or perhaps the problem was miscopied? Commenting this now instead of an answer because of the uncertainty...

Comment: (where the first step relies on seeing that
$$e^{t \sum_{i=1}^{n+1}Y_i}=e^{tY_{n+1}} e^{t \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i},$$
hence
$$\mathbb{E}(M_{n+1} | \mathscr{F}_n)=\frac{1}{m_Y(t)}\mathbb{E}(e^{tY_{n+1}} e^{t \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i}| \mathscr{F}_n),$$ by properties of exponential)

Comment: @NapD.Lover I agree with you, there is an issue in the definition of $M_n$. I suggest the following: $M_n = \frac{\exp(t\sum_{i=1}^nY_i)}{m_y(t)^n}$. Therefore, as per the comment above : $E[M_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n] =\frac{e^{t \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i}}{m_Y(t)^{n+1}}\mathbb{E}(e^{tY_{n+1}}| \mathcal{F}_n) = M_n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The candidate martingale has perhaps been miscopied. As per the comment by @Sesame, if instead one defines $M_n$ by
$$M_n = \frac{\exp(t\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i)}{m_Y(t)^n},$$
then the usual computations carry through to show this is a martingale.

Summarizing the steps presented in the comment, we compute
$$\mathbb{E}(M_{n+1}|\mathscr{F}_n)=\frac{1}{m_Y(t)^{n+1}}\exp(t \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i)\mathbb{E}(\exp(tY_{n+1})|\mathscr{F}_n)$$
$$=\frac{M_n}{m_Y(t)}\mathbb{E}(\exp(tY_{n+1}))=M_n$$
where we have, first, used the "pulling out what is known" property since $\exp(t \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i) \in \mathscr{F}_n$ and, second, used that $\exp(t Y_{n+1})$ is independent of $\mathscr{F}_n$. Thus $\mathbb{E}(M_{n+1}|\mathscr{F}_n)=M_n$, so $M_n$ is a martingale as desired.

Comment: Could I ask you how to prove integrability of $M_{n}$, that is $\mathbb{E}|M_{n}|<\infty$? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Laura it follows directly from the fact all the $Y$ are IID, the MGF is assumed finite over the reals, properties of exponentials and expectations of independent products: $$\mathbb{E}(|M_n|)=(1/m_Y(t)^n) \mathbb{E}(e^{Y_1 t})\cdot \dotsc \cdot \mathbb{E}(e^{Y_n t})$$ all these factors are assumed to be finite in the OP. Hence $\mathbb{E}(|M_n|) < \infty$. How’s that sound?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it sounds good. I did not realize that $\frac{\exp^{(t\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_{i})}}{m_Y(t)^{n}}>0$ so $\mathbb{E}|\frac{\exp^{(t\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_{i})}}{m_Y(t)^{n}}|=\mathbb{E}(\frac{\exp^{(t\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_{i})}}{m_Y(t)^{n}})$. Next $\frac{1}{m_Y(t)^{n}}\in\mathbb{R}$ and all $\mathbb{E}e^{tY_{i}}<\infty$.